# $p$ is a projection iff $p$ is normal the spectrum of $p$ is contained in $\{0,1\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

I want to know why the following claim is true: Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra. $p\in A$ is a projection (that means $p^2=p^*=p$) iff p is normal and $\sigma (p)\subseteq \{0,1\}$.

"$\implies$" why p normal, it is clear. I know that $\sigma(p)\subseteq [-1,1]$, since $\sigma(p)\subseteq [-\|p\|,\|p\|]$ and $p$ projection, therefore: $\|p\|=1$. But its not enough. (If $A$ is a vector space and $p$ an endomorphism, then i know how to prove it, i consider $p^2-p=p(p-1)$ ). Maybe i have to use the continuous functional calculus, but i dont know how. Can anyone help me? And can you give me a hint how to do "$\impliedby$" ? Regards
Edit: Maybe i could use $f(x)=x^2-x$ and functional calculus to prove "$\impliedby$". But I don't know how to do this in detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $p$ is normal and $\sigma(p)\subseteq \{ 0, 1\}$, then the spectral mapping theory gives $\sigma(p(p-1))=\{0\}$. Because $p$ is normal, then the spectral radius and the norm are the same, which gives $p(p-1)=0$ or $p^{2}=p$. A normal operator with spectrum $\sigma(p)\subset\mathbb{R}$ must be selfadjoint.

Okay, the opposite direction. If $p^{2}=p^{\star}=p$, then $p$ is normal because it is selfadjont. To show that $\sigma(p)\subseteq\{0,1\}$, you can directly determine the resolvent for $\lambda \notin \{0,1\}$. Write
$$
                 \lambda 1- p = \lambda(1-p+p)-p= \lambda(1-p)+(\lambda-1) p.
$$
Then the inverse is easily spotted because $p(1-p)=0$, $p^{2}=p$, and $(1-p)^{2}=1-p$:
$$
                  (\lambda 1-p)^{-1} = \frac{1}{\lambda}(1-p)+\frac{1}{\lambda-1}p.
$$
So $\sigma(p)\subseteq\{0,1\}$ because $(\lambda 1-p)^{-1}$ exists for all other $\lambda$.

Comment: ok, that helps me. meanwhile i have the direction => and with your answer, i understand <=. Thank you

Comment: @Teddy : I added the part that $p^{2}=p$ implies $\sigma(p)\subseteq\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Nice check! :D Would you mind adding this to: [Projections: Spectrum](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1354568/79762) *(Copy&Paste would be fine.)*

Comment: @Freeze_S : I answer the question for you.