# Projections: Spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

Given a unital C*-algebra $1\in\mathcal{A}$.

> For projection one has:
>   $$P^2=P=P^*\iff\sigma(P)\subseteq\{0,1\}\quad(P=P^*)$$

And all cases can appear:
$$\sigma(0)=\{0\}\quad\sigma(0\oplus1)=\{0,1\}\quad\sigma(1)=\{1\}$$

How can I check this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First write
$$
         \lambda I-P = \lambda(I-P+P)-P = \lambda(I-P)+(\lambda-1)P.
$$

If $P^{2}=P$ then $(I-P)^{2}=(I-P)$ and $P(I-P)=(I-P)P=0$, and the inverse of the above expression can be spotted for $\lambda\notin\{0,1\}$:
$$
        (\lambda I-P)^{-1} = \frac{1}{\lambda}(I-P)+\frac{1}{\lambda-1}P.
$$

Therefore $\sigma(P)\subseteq \{0,1\}$. And $0\in\sigma(P) \iff P=I$. Likewise $1\notin\sigma(P) \iff P=0$. This part is true of all projections, self-adjoint or not.

Conversely, suppose $\sigma(P)\subseteq \{0,1\}$ and $P=P^{\star}$. Then $Q=P(I-P)$ has spectrum $\sigma(Q)=\{0\}$ by the spectral mapping theorem for polynomials. However, $\|Q\|=r_{\sigma}(Q)=0$ because $Q$ is selfajdoint. So $P=P^{2}$.

Comment: @Freeze_S : I plussed 1 to get you back up to 0, too.

Comment: Very nice from you!!

Comment: @TrialAndError I just didn't understand why $\| Q \| = r_\sigma(Q)$. If you don't mind, could you explain me this? Thanks.

Comment: @Integral : $\|Q\|=r_{\sigma}(Q)$ for any bounded selfadjoint operator. This is because $\|Q^2\|=\|Q\|^2$ for a selfadjoint operator.

Comment: I see, so this proof won't work for a general Banach algebra instead a $C^\ast$-algebra..

Comment: @Integral : This question was about $C^*$ algebras, so I didn't bother to consider anything else.